# How to call a non abstract method of an abstract class directly without deriving the abstract class?

Tags: c#

I have an abstract class which contains a non abstract method as follows.

```
abstract class myClass {     
    public void myNonAbstractMethod()
    {
        //some logic goes here...
    }   
}
```

Now my question is, is it possible to call `myNonAbstractMethod()` directly without deriving `myClass`?

Comment: No. You can not create an instance of an abstract class; only an instance of a non abstract derived class. Why do you ask? Is this an academic question?

Comment: If you want to call instance method of abstract class, are you sure, that this class should be abstract?

Comment: Maybe it can be done with some reflection magic, but maybe you only think you need this, but actually don't. We need more information on your motives to know what is the proper answer.

Comment: If you find yourself wanting this, then you made an error along the way.

Answer (score 5):

No, as `abstract class` can not be instantiated by itself. You *have to* derive from it in order to be able to construct an instance.

```
 public abstract class Base {

   public void BaseMethod() {
   }
 }

 var bs = new Base();  //FAIL TO COPMILE
```

but..

```
 public class Derived : Base {

 }

 var bs = new Derived ();  //OK
 bs.BaseMethod(); //OK
```

Comment: Hi @Tigran thanks for your example i know what you explained here but I was little bit confused.So, just for the sake clarification i put this question

Answer (score 5):

You cannot instantiate an abstract class meaning you aren't able to call an instance method directly from it.

You can make the method `static` if you really don't want to derive it, but a subclass would be best.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println(SomeTest.size());
    }
}

abstract class SomeTest {
    public static int size() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Output:

> 5

Comment: Recommending making a method static without understanding what its intended purpose is, is probably not the right thing to do.. In fact; it's not good advice at all.

Comment: @daveL: I did the exact opposite.

Comment: Really? Your answer reads exactly like you recommended making an instance method static.. Maybe I misread it.

Comment: "You can make the method static if you really don't want to derive it, but a subclass would be best." I'm merely providing options. He asked for a way to do this without creating a subclass, making the method `static` will be the easiest way to go about this. Although I stress that derivation would be best, he knows about this already.

Comment: Hi @JeroenVannevel thanks for the fastest reply. I know that by making the above method myNonAbstractMethod() as static will solve the problem but I was little bit confused when there is no inheritance. That's why I raised this very basic question.